# How to load a csv file in MATLAB by skipping erroneous rows?

Tags: matlab, csv

I am using the `csvread` command to read a large CSV file:

```
M=csvread('myfile.csv');
```

But there are few rows in it, apparently, which do not allow MATLAB to load the file because of being text (or otherwise garbage). For example, line number 45372, 117573, etc. So, how do I skip them when loading the file?

Comment: what error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

When *few* mean already few you can use `try-catch` structure in `while` loop. It is also needed to know number of columns.

Following code expect error message:

> `Mismatch between file and format string.
>   Trouble reading number from file (row <row#>, field <field#>) ==> <faulty line content>`

The code tries to load whole `csv` in once. If it fails it analyses error message, identifies the faulty line, loads the file to the line before and appends the result to the `data` variable. In next run it starts loading one line below the faulty line. This iteration is terminated when the remaining file is succesfully read to the end.

```
StartRow=<number of ignored rows (header)>;
Ncols=<width>;
data=zeros(0,Ncols);
csvFault=true;
while csvFault
  try
    Temp=csvread('YourFile.csv',StartRow,0)       % Try to read file from StartRow to the end-of-file.
    csvFault=false;                               % Executed only when CSVread is succesful
  catch msg
    %% Error occured
    faultyRow=regexp(msg.message,' ','split');   % Split error message into cells
    faultyRow=faultyRow{12};                     % 12th cell contain row identifier
    faultyRow=str2double(faultyRow(1:end-1));    % Identifier is number followed by 1 letter

    %% Read the data from the segment between faulty lines
    Temp=csvread('YourFile.csv',StartRow,0,[StartRow,0,faultyRow-1,Ncols-1])

    StartRow=faultyRow+1;
  end
  data=[data;Temp];
end
```